# synonyms for conflicts of interest?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

My Roget's and online sources aren't helpful. I'm looking for words or short phrases that can be used as synonyms for conflicts of interest.

thanks!

Comment: Your question is going to be closed unless you can provide evidence of any research that you have done. For example, what synonyms have you found for *war*, the ultimate conflict of interest?

Comment: @Mick - I don't see how you can regard "war" as a synonym for "conflict of interest".

Comment: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/conflict-of-interest-s) comes up with "favoritism" and "unfairness", though those are not particularly synonymous, in my opinion.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest) gives the specific subtypes of *nepotism* and *self-dealing*.  There is also the term *quid pro quo*, which may or may not represent a COI.  You might also use the vaguer term "lack of impartiality".

Answer (score 1):

*"conflict of interest"* has no direct sysnonyms. It is a uniquely expressive phrase and has few shortform equivalences.

Although depending on context, you could potentially use *bias*, *nepotism*, *partiallity*, *partisanship*, *preferential treatment*, etc.

However these, and other similar words/phrases, don't capture the exact meaning of "conflict of interest".